# Perfect Ideal Gas Modelization of Air

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas

I'm solving a Thermodynamic problem. I have Air at temperature of 293.15 K, and pressure of 20 MPa. I would understand if is possible to consider this an Ideal Gas or not (and if is possible which are the limit of pressure and temperature with i can still consider air as an Ideal Gas).

Thankyou very much.

Samuele

Comment: A homework question? Really? Whether this is a set problem or not I don't know, but it doesn't look like a homework problem in the sense this site usually uses.

Answer (score 1):

I tried a quick Google but couldn't find any data on this. However you can use the [Van der Waals equation of state](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_equation) to get some idea how big the deviations are going to be. The ideal gas law (for one mole) is:

$$ PV = RT $$

and feeding in $P = 20\text{MPa}$ and $T = 293\text{K}$ I get $V = 1.22 \times 10^{-4}m^3$. The Van der Waals equation of state is (again for one mole):

$$ \left( P + \frac{a}{V^2}\right)\left(V - b\right) = RT $$

and from [this web site](http://faculty.wwu.edu/vawter/PhysicsNet/Topics/Thermal/vdWaalEquatOfState.html) I found values for air of $a = 0.1358\text{Jm}^3\text{mole}^{-2}$ and $b = 3.64 \times 10^{-5}\text{m}^3\text{mole}^{-1}$. If we now use these values and the calculated value for $V$ in the Van der Waals equation we get:

$$ \left( 2\times 10^7 + 9.2\times 10^6\right)\left(1.22\times 10^{-4} - 3.64 \times 10^{-5}\right) = RT $$

So the non-ideal terms are large compared to the pressure and volume. I think it's safe to say air is highly non-ideal under these circumstances. In fact with such large corrections even the VdW equation may well be outside its region of validity.

Comment: thankyou very much for your answer, is very clear. but how can i recognize during the exam when a gas is modelizable as ideal or not? i will have tables with the properties of the gas (cv, cp, k, R) and the properties on the saturation (v, u, s, h, T) given the pressure... but nothing more.